# How to set isHardwareAccelerated value for Android View

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, view, hardware-acceleration

Working on Kotlin `WebView`,

```
val webView = WebView(this)
.....
webView.isHardwareAccelerated = true
```

returns compiler error ,

> > Val cannot be reassigned

How can I set `isHardwareAccelerated = true` for web view?

#### Update

This mod [Rathod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7666442/nilesh-rathod) marked it as possibly duplicate and even closed the post without noticing the title of the post. I know when does this exception occurs. What I don't know is, how to modify  the `isHardwareAccelerated` value on other way.

Comment: @NileshRathod please read the post carefully before marking as duplicated. I know when this exception occurs, what I don't know is how to change the `isHardwareAccelerated` value on other way.

Comment: Check the doc https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel#view-level

Comment: @RodrigoQueiroz I have used `setLayerType()` as per documents suggestion but my `webView.isHardwareAccelerated` still returning false. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
```

Good luck!

Comment: @Demidov I have applied but `webView.isHardwareAccelerated` still returning `false`

Comment: Could you set android:hardwareAccelerated="true" for Activity but not for only WebView?

Comment: @Demidov I have already set true for Application, Activity and WebView. No luck so far. Did you try yourself and it worked for you?

Comment: I set true for Activity and it worked but I did not check isHardwareAccelerated for WebView exactly.